# Communication between client and server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to make a client and server app. The client would be able to send a request and receive the relevant data that the server would make. The client would run on a single computer with a static IP address and the clients would run on multiple machines.

So far I've been trying to use Remoting but couldn't get it to work properly as all the examples I found seem to be old, is this the best way to enable this service or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using sockets?

Comment: @Rick you generally don't want to use sockets yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer that was posted by sipwiz on this question: [How can I send data over the internet using a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726115/how-can-i-send-data-over-the-internet-using-a-socket) , I modified the code to send and recive a serialized tuple and it works great for my needs.