# Asynchronous Socket Connection

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, tcpclient, system.net

Are there any fast way to learn Asynchronous socket tcp programming or are there any libraries available to utilize system.socket in a short amount of time?

My synchronous tcp client couldn't hold the program I'm working on because it needs to listen for a long period of time (10 to 60 seconds), which of course doesn't work in synchronous connection.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you could quickly whip up some code copycatting from msdn's async [server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx) and [client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx) samples. then again, by the time it took you and me to post you could probably have mastered the basics already...

Comment: this post may be a (partial) duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104617/what-is-a-good-tutorial-howto-on-net-c-socket-programming in which is refered to an old but great MSDN tutorial on sockets

Comment: @mtijn: Actually I checked msdn and googled for hours for possible solutions, but I couldn't get them to work. How about libraries are there any? I'm using c#

Comment: well what's wrong with just the .NET Sockets? They support async sockets too, as demonstrated in the 2 articles of my first comment. if you have a demo of your attempts post it so we can better help you overcome any difficulties.

Comment: This is a perfect use case for the Async CTP - there are multiple samples on using the async/await keywords to use the waiting time to do other useful work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I stand corrected. It appears that an synchronous socket does work for listening for long period of time. The reason why my earlier attempt wasn't working is because I'm using a `NetworkStream`, but I found out that it's possible to use a socket without a `NetworkStream`.

```
Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                 SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Then use

`socket.Send` and `socket.Receive`